# pdf print using php but does not print data from database

Tags: php, pdf

This line to call the PDF page, but I don't know is it right or wrong:

```
<td><a href="pdf.php?pdf=1&tid='.$row["tid"].'"<button name="btn_print"class="btn btn-primary btn-icon-text btn-rounded"><i class="ti-clipboard btn-icon-prepend">
</i>View PDF</button></td>
```

if u want to solve please use this type of pdf format
This is the line to print all the information, but the output just prints the data that not from database:

```
<?php
//pdf.php;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chromium");  
$id=$_POST["id"];
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
        $sql="SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE CID = '".$id."'"; 
        $query=mysqli_query($sql); 
        $row=mysqli_fetch_object($query) ;
     if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))
     {
        $data .='<h1>Your Details</h1>';
        $data .='<strong>Name</strong>'.$row['CNAME'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Vocation</strong>'.$row['CVoca'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Email</strong>'.$row['CEmail'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Phone Number</strong>'.$row['CPNum'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Qualification</strong>'.$row['CQualify'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>University</strong>'.$row['CUni'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Gender</strong>'.$row['CGender'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Date of Birth</strong>'.$row['CDate'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Address</strong>'.$row['CAddress'].'<br />';
     }
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHtml($data);

$mpdf->Output('candidate.pdf','D');
?>
```

helpp mee

Comment: You haven't closed your `<a>` tag before the `<button>` tag.

Comment: please print $data and check what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one i hope your problem will be solve

```
<a href="https://fpdf.en.uptodown.com/windows/download">download fpdf file</a>
<br><br>

<td>
    <a href="?pdf=1&tid=3">
        <button name="btn_print"class="btn btn-primary btn-icon-text btn-rounded">
        <i class="ti-clipboard btn-icon-prepend"></i>
            view pdf
        </button>
    </a>
</td>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<?php
if (isset($_get['pdf'])) {

ob_start();
include "fpdf/fpdf.php";
$pdf = new fpdf('p','mm','a4');

$pdf->addpage();

$pdf->setfont('arial','b',20);

$pdf->cell(190  ,5,'your details',0,1,'c');
$pdf->cell(190  ,5,'',0,1);

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chromium");  
$id=$_get["tid"];
        $sql="select * from candidate  where cid ='$id'"; 
        $query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql); 
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
     {


        $pdf->setfont('arial','b',18);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,'name',0,0);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','',16);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,$row['cname'],0,1);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','b',18);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,'vocation',0,0);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','',16);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,$row['cvoca'],0,1);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','b',18);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,'email',0,0);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','',16);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,$row['cemail'],0,1);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,'phone number',0,0);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','',16);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,$row['cpnum'],0,1);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','b',18);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,'qualification',0,0);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','',16);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,$row['cqualify'],0,1);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','b',18);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,'university',0,0);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','',16);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,$row['cuni'],0,1);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,'gender',0,0);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','',16);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,$row['cgender'],0,1);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','b',18);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,'date of birth',0,0);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','',16);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,$row['cdate'],0,1);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','b',18);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,'address',0,0);
        $pdf->setfont('arial','',16);
        $pdf->cell(90  ,5,$row['caddress'],0,1);

     }
$pdf->output();
ob_end_flush(); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
//pdf.php;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chromium");  
$id=$_POST["id"];
// 1. You haven't defined $sql yet to use in below line of query and also you are not using $result anymore,
// if not required remove this line
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE CID = '".$id."'"; 

        // 2. mysqli_query() accepts two parameter connection and query but you have given only query
        // Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
        $query=mysqli_query($sql); 
        $row=mysqli_fetch_object($query) ;
     if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))
     {
        $data .='<h1>Your Details</h1>';
        $data .='<strong>Name</strong>'.$row['CNAME'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Vocation</strong>'.$row['CVoca'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Email</strong>'.$row['CEmail'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Phone Number</strong>'.$row['CPNum'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Qualification</strong>'.$row['CQualify'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>University</strong>'.$row['CUni'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Gender</strong>'.$row['CGender'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Date of Birth</strong>'.$row['CDate'].'<br />';
        $data .='<strong>Address</strong>'.$row['CAddress'].'<br />';
     }
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHtml($data);

$mpdf->Output('candidate.pdf','D');
?>
```

Find my above two comments in code which may help you

So, If you resolve my second comment you probably get the data check it once